# Python: Bytes Object and Open -- How to create equivalent files?

Tags: python

I have a type `bytes` file loaded in memory. How can I create identical files, as-if I was loading from my disk with `open`?

Consider the following:

```
type(downloaded_bytes)  # bytes
f = io.StringIO(downloaded_bytes.decode('utf-8')).readlines()
f2 = open(r"file.log", "r").readlines()
f == f2  # false
```

The large thing I noticed inspecting the files is that retrieving the file as bytes has replaced linebreaks. For example, in `f2`, a line reads like this:

`'Initializing error logging... Success\n',`

While in the bytes derived file, `f`, the same line reads:

`'Initializing error logging... Success\r\n',`

In other areas, `\n` (the expected line break), is replaced by `\r` in the bytes file.

How might I force `f` to be exactly like `f2` here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable line ending translations, while still operating on `str`, the correct solution is to pass `newline=''` (or `newline=""`) to `open`. It still decodes the input to `str`, and recognizes any form of line separator (`\r\n`, `\n` or `\r`) as a line break, but it doesn't normalize the line separator to a simple `\n`:

```
with open(r"file.log", newline='') as f2in:  # Demonstrating with with statement for guarantee close
    f2 = f2in.readlines()
```

Alternatively, to get rid of the `\r` in the downloaded bytes rather than preserving it in the file read from disk, the simplest solution is to just perform the line-ending translation yourself (adding `import os` to top of file if needed to get `os.linesep` definition):

```
f = io.StringIO(downloaded_bytes.decode('utf-8').replace(os.linesep, '\n')).readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running on Windows. Which, by convention, uses `'\r\n'` to terminate lines in "text mode". Open your file in "binary mode" instead:

```
f2 = open(r"file.log", "rb").readlines()
```

Note the trailing `b` in the second argument to `open()`. Then line-end translations won't happen.

Comment: Indeed, I edited my post but I want `f` to be exactly like `f2`

Comment: Unfortunately, this also disables the automatic decode from `str` to `bytes` as well. If you want to compare the raw bytes, this is a better approach, but if the goal is to convert to the same lines you'd see from the file, you'd still want `str` at the end.

Comment: I don't know - and can't guess - what the OP wants, exactly. They'll have to be more explicit, or settle for a variety of answers that may or may not address what they actually want ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't use StringIO for binary stuff, use [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o)!

```py
from io import BytesIO

f = BytesIO(downloaded_bytes)
```